# xpath get by div id not working

Tags: php, html, xpath

my script dont get any results(blank page) and i dont understand why
I've used this script on other websites and work

$url = 'http://ip-score.com/checkip/207.224.78.193';

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$my_xpath_query = "//div[@id='MaxMind']";
$result_rows = $xpath->query($my_xpath_query);

foreach ($result_rows as $result_object){
echo $result_object->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

i've aspect to get this results:

```
207.224.78.193  United States
State: Minnesota
City: Minneapolis
ZIP: 55407
Hostname: 207-224-78-193.mpls.qwest.net, Whois
Organization: CenturyLink, History
ISP: CenturyLink
Mail Server: N\A
IP range: 207.224.71.0 - 207.224.97.191
Current region time: Thu 12th Mar 2015 - 02:52:15 GMT: -05:00
Region timezone: America/Chicago
```

i want to get all info from url(state,city,zip...) but i can not get it one by one so i decise to get all then split it into var

Comment: Try to change `"/div[@id='MaxMind']"` to `//div[@id='MaxMind']//text()`. In for loop try to `print_r($result_object)` print the result. you will get nodes.I think this will works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpath expression is currently looking for that div as the root element of the document. You probably want to use `//div[@id='MaxMind']` to search the document entirely, or just use `$dom->getElementById("MaxMind")` as xpath isn't really needed for this query.

Also worth noting: the first child of that element is just a text node full of white space. To dump out everything in the div replace

```
echo $result_object->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

with

```
echo $result_object->nodeValue;
```

Though if you want to get at that stuff in a more reasonable manner, instead of just one blob of text, an xpath expression like `//div[@id='MaxMind']/p` will give you each "line" within.

Comment: i've tested with //div[@id='MaxMind'] and still the same problem

Comment: i want to get all text from that url then i will split it by new lines into variable

Comment: @AllCapone1912 Explaining it does not exactly help - edit your question and _show_ the output you expect.

Comment: Yes,its work exact like i need Thanks for your help **echo $result_object->nodeValue; - work for me**